# Load page after Ajax is inserted Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, setinterval, clearinterval

Within jQuery Mobile I am using a mutli page ajax system. What I want to do is when a user selects a page the jquery loader appears and the other page only shows after the ajax is inserted into the page.

For example if I have a page `#list` and another page `#listdetails` I want when a user selects a list item on the list page then it loads, showing loading graphic. The listdetails page is only shown to the user when the page is loaded totally with the ajax content. How can this be done any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, I made an example for you. It is not 100% what you have wanted but you will get the point: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/

Basically what I do in my example is showing ajax loader when page is about to be hidden:

```
$(document).live('pagebeforehide', '[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){  
    var loader = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        clearInterval(loader);
    },1); 
});
```

And hide it when page is loaded:

```
$(document).live('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){  
    var loader = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        clearInterval(loader);
    },1); 
});
```

setInterval is here because web kit browser have a problem showing ajax loader in any even except pageshow.

You can use my code to hide ajax loader when page is shown but sometimes your ajax will successfully end after pageshow so let say this is your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host,
    dataType: "xml",
    data: somedata,
    success: function(xml) {
        //Do something
        hideloader();           
    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        //Report an error
        hideloader();
    }
});

function hideloader() {
    var loader = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        clearInterval(loader);
    },1); 
}
```

In this case I have used 2 loaders